# Transactional email footer icons are not displaying as a row in mobile view

Tags: transactional-mail, magento2.2.3, footer

I have used the html table to create the **footer** for **Transaction email**.

I'm getting an expected view(Horizontal)in desktop view but vertical in mobile view.

Below is the code i have used to create and design the footer.

```
                  <td class="footer" style="background-color:#FFCD00;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:143px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="footer-blog">
                                  <a class="icon-blogg-footer" href="http://mywebsite/blogg">
                                 <img src="" alt="image">
                                 </a>
                           </td>    
                           <td class="footer-facebook">
                                         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebsite">
                                         <img src="" alt="image">
                                         </a>
                           </td>
                           <td class="footer-instagram">
                                 <a href="https://instagram.com/mywebsite">
                                 <img src="" alt="image">
                                 </a>        
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
```

Unfortunately, the **media quer**y is not supporting for mail clients like yahoo, outlook.

Please comment with your suggestion. Thanks.